# First array element getting overwritten by the second when getting data from db using PHP

Tags: php

I have a few lines of code that start something like this:

```
$trailheads = array();
// Then a db call with a query.  Then loop through the results.

// This gives a diff value every time, so here we are still ok
$trailhead->trailhead_name = $row['trailhead_name']; 

// Before the look iteration ends, I do something like this:
array_push ( $trailheads , $trailhead );
// But I could have done this with the same result:
$trailheads[] = $trailhead;
```

And once I exit the loop, I do print_r and it shows that the second of the two rows returned by the query over-wrote the first.

Here is the full version of the loop:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($trailhead_result))
    {
        $trailhead->trailhead_name = $row['trailhead_name'];


        $trailhead->park_id = $row['park_id'];
        $trailhead->trailhead_id = $row['trailhead_id'];
        $trailhead->trailhead_description = $row['trailhead_description'];
        $trailhead->parking = $row['parking'];
        $trailhead->lat = $row['lat'];
        $trailhead->lng = $row['lng'];
        $trailhead->is_free = $row['is_free'];
        $trailhead->parking_spots = $row['parking_spots'];
        $trailhead->cost_details = $row['cost_details'];

        $trailheads[] = $trailhead;
    }
```

Comment: are you reinitializing the value of $trailhead each time?  it might help to post a fuller version of the loop

Comment: Try doing a `print_r()` during your loop, so you can see exactly where and why your array is getting overwritten.

Comment: Just posted a fuller version of the loop.  @jnpcl Good idea - will try that now.  I did it just after the loop and it was already bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's your full loop, then one problem is that you're not initializing `$trailhead` **inside** the loop.  Do this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($trailhead_result))
{
    $trailhead = new trailhead();
    $trailhead->trailhead_name = $row['trailhead_name'];
    $trailhead->park_id = $row['park_id'];
    $trailhead->trailhead_id = $row['trailhead_id'];
    $trailhead->trailhead_description = $row['trailhead_description'];
    $trailhead->parking = $row['parking'];
    $trailhead->lat = $row['lat'];
    $trailhead->lng = $row['lng'];
    $trailhead->is_free = $row['is_free'];
    $trailhead->parking_spots = $row['parking_spots'];
    $trailhead->cost_details = $row['cost_details'];

    $trailheads[] = $trailhead;
}
```

I have to assume that the object `$trailhead` is a class called `trailhead`.  If it's not, use whatever class is correct in place of `new trailhead()`.